# Obter uso de memória de aplicação específica

Tags: c#

Estou precisando obter o uso de memória e de CPU de uma aplicação em c#, com o código abaixo (utilizando [`PerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx)) não obtive o mesmo valor do Gerenciador de Tarefas do [Windows](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows).

```
PerformanceCounter cpu;
PerformanceCounter ram;

cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "Servidor - estoque", true);
ram = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Private Bytes", "Servidor - estoque", true);

int Cpu = Convert.ToInt32(cpu.NextValue());
int Ram = Convert.ToInt32(ram.NextValue());


CPU.Value = Cpu;
RAM.Value = (Ram/1024/1024);
```

Como faço para que o valor gasto de memória e CPU de uma determinada aplicação seja a mesma demonstrada no Gerenciador de Tarefas?

Answer (score 3):

Se quiser obter a memória de um outro processo, do qual saiba o PID, pode usar [`GetProcessById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var mem = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(1234).PrivateMemorySize64; // valor em bytes
```

Por outro lado, se souber o nome do processo, pode usar [`GetProcessesByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.110).aspx). Tenha em conta que `GetProcessByName` retorna um *array* de processos (vários processos distintos podem partilhar o mesmo nome (e.g Chrome)). Posto isso, pode imprimir a memória dos diferentes processos assim:

```
foreach(var proc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("nome")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
}
```

Relativamente aos valores que quer obter, veja [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) uma lista completa das propriedades disponibilizadas pelo objecto `Process`.

Comment: Este código demonstra o uso de memória real do aplicativo? eu testei e não mostrou o uso demonstrado no Gerenciador de tarefas

Comment: Esse código mostra a quantidade de memoria usada (e não partilhada), no momento, pelo processo. Tenha em conta que o valor e apresentado em bytes e que o valor no gerenciador de tarefas e mostrado em kB, logo para obter o valor em kB tem de dividir o valor por 1024.

Comment: Aconselho a leitura deste [artigo](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2016/01/05/windows-process-memory-usage-demystified/) (em inglês) sobre os diferentes tipos de memoria de um processo.

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que você deve utilizar "Processor Information" ao invés de "Process", no primeiro parâmetro:

```
cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "Servidor - estoque", true);
ram = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "Private Bytes", "Servidor - estoque", true);
```

Comment: Deu a seguinte mensagem: _Não foi possível localizar o Contador de Desempenho com o nome de categoria especificado 'Processor Information', nome do contador 'Private Bytes'._

Answer (score 2):

Para o consumo privado de memória utilize o método [`GetCurrentProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) para referenciar o processo atual; o valor da propriedade [`PrivateMemorySize64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx) indicará a o tamanho em bytes.

Um *oneliner* seria assim:

```
var tamanhoEmBytes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
```

Comment: Preciso disso para outro processo independente da aplicação com este código